# How to access the contact details within the WhatsApp app in android mobile development?

Tags: java, android, api, whatsapp

I'm creating a mobile app which has a feature for accessing the contact details from Facebook and Whatsapp. 
Facebook has a good SDK which makes acccessing facebooks contact details very easy. 
However I can't find any api/sdk or documention on Whatsapp as how to access it's features.
Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this official developer link from Whatsapp.
[WhatsApp Merging into other Android apps](https://www.whatsapp.com/faq/en/android/28000012)